# how can remove last comma from json using javascript forloop

Tags: javascript, php, json

```
    $('#save').click(function() {
    var loopvalue = "<?php echo $count; ?>"
    var datajson = '[';
    //alert(loopvalue + "length of array")
    for (i = 1; i < loopvalue; i++) {
        var fetchid = '.A' + i;
        var fetchid_code = '.C' + i;
        datajson = datajson + "{" + "maincode :" + $('#company').val() + ",acode : " + $(fetchid_code).text() +
            " , Amount :" + $(fetchid).val() + ", periodfrom :" + $('#dFrom').val() +
            ", periodto : " + $('#dTo').val() + ", danounc : " + $('#dano').val() +
            ", period : " + $('#period').val() + ", fyear : " + $('#fyear').val() +
            ", frequency : " + $('#freq').val() + ", stype : " + $('#stype').val() +
            ", sseq : " + $('#sseq').val() + " }, "

    }
    datajson = datajson + ']'
        //console.log(datajson);

    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'jsondecode.php',
        data: {
            datajson: JSON.stringify(datajson)
        },
        //data:postArray,
        dataType: "json",
        success: function(data) {
            console.log("success:", data);
        },
        failure: function(errMsg) {
            console.error("error:", errMsg);
        }
    });
});
```

first i remove last comma in `json` object and second when i am calling `ajax` page but it is displaying NULL value in `jsonencode.php` page how can I solve this problem any can suggest me this is my server site script now

```
 <?php
     header('Content-Type: application/json');    
    $data = json_decode($_POST["datajson"]);
// will echo the JSON.stringified - string:
echo $_POST["datajson"];
// will echo the json_decode'd object
var_dump($data);
//traversing the whole object and accessing properties:
foreach ($data as $Object) {
    echo "maincode: " . $Object->maincode . ", Acode: " . $Object->acode . "<br/>";
}
?>
```

Comment: Why are you manually building your JSON string? Create an array, push elements into the array inside your loop, and then use JSON.stringify() on the result. (Also, why create an array of objects with so much redundant data? 9/11 properties are the same in every object.)

Answer (score 3):

Or maybe you should use actual object instead of string-concatenation

Try this

```
var datajson = [];
for (i = 1; i < loopvalue ; i++) 
{
    var fetchid = '.A' + i;
    var fetchid_code = '.C' + i;
    var obj = {
        maincode : $('#company').val(),
        acode   : $(fetchid_code).text(),
        Amount  : $(fetchid).val(),
        periodfrom : $('#dFrom').val(),
        periodto   : $('#dTo').val(),
        danounc    : $('#dano').val(),
        period    : $('#period').val(),
        fyear    : $('#fyear').val(),
        frequency    : $('#freq').val(),
        stype    : $('#stype').val(),
        sseq    : $('#sseq').val()
    }
    datajson.push( obj );
}
datajson = JSON.stringify( datajson ); //converting to string here
```

Comment: i have this code but when i call ajax page  var selecboxpage = '/financeupload/jsondecode.php?json=datajson';
                        alert(datajson);
  
  
  
  
   
 $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: selecboxpage,
        async:true,
        data:datajson,
        dataType:"json",
        success: function(data){
      console.log("success:",data);},
        failure: function(errMsg) {
      
        }
        
     })
 
             return false; data not display in my decode page

Answer (score 0):

Write the single elements of your look into an array and then join the elements.

See here: [javascript join](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_join.asp)

But of course building JSON yourself is not necessary. Use [JSON.stringify](http://www.json.org/js.html) for that.

Answer (score 0):

Before you append `]` to `datajson`, `substring` that value to remove last `,`. That is.

```
datajson = datajson.toString().subString(0, datajson.toString().length - 1);
```

Then Append `]`

It is not needed to use `JSON.stringify(datajson)` in `data` attribute of `$.ajax` because you are sending the json string. not json object.

Hope this helps

Comment: i add datajson= datajson.toString().subString(0, datajson.toString().length - 1); before ] they show TypeError: datajson.toString(...).subString is not a function

Comment: Please use `substring()` not subString(). and one more thing is to deduct 2 from length as you have appended a blank space after comma